# Use Outlets from objective C file, in swift file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, outlet

I have a view controller with the corresponding .h and .m files written in Objective C, but I would like to be able to modify this view's properties from a Swift file. 
Any Idea how to achieve so please ?

Comment: You should never modify another class's IBOutlets. This has nothing to do with ObjC/Swift. You should never do it in any language. But for more general issues (such as configuring an ObjC view controller that you're segueing to from a Swift view controller), see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html for how to set this up. For more on the MVC pattern and how view controllers should interact, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. Apologies if I expressed myself wrongly. What I mean is for instance, I created a UIButton in a viewController from the Objective-C file, and I wish to modify this last in my Swift file (such as changing its color). I have a bridging header, and I can access the functions (or methods) of the Objective-C file/class, but I can seem to figure out how to access the button.

Comment: Is this an extension of your view controller then, written in Swift? Or some other object? A small excerpt of the code may make it much clearer.